# How to have sub-points in a powerpoint presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

This is likely very simple. In a powerpoint presentation, it's easy to have a bulleted list of items.  How do you get a sub-bulleted list under a single bullet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely sure because I don't have PowerPoint to test, but if you press enter after the first bullet-point, then press tab, it will do what you want.

Comment: @coffee, in addition to accepting this answer, you can also upvote it by clicking on the up arrow (I'm the one upvote at present).  This gives James more rep points for his efforts.

Answer (score 6):

Tab only changes the indentation and not the bullet style

Promote bullet = alt + shift  + right arrow

Demote bullet = alt + shift  + left arrow

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer buttons to keyboard shortcuts, you can also place the cursor in the bullet point that you wish to change the level of, and then click on the "Increase List Level" button.

In PowerPoint 2007, it's on the `Home` tab, in the `Paragraph` box, as the fourth item over to the right on the first row.  It has an arrow pointing to the right at a set of bars.